# I am using knob.js jquery plugin. I want to set the minimum value of the widget to 100

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-knob

I am using knob.js jquery plugin. I want to set the minimum value of the widget to 100 (i.e i want to display full circle) but the input value must be displayed as 1 or 2

Jquery plugin link : http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/

Check about us section here for the demo : http://themeisle.com/demo/?theme=Zerif%20Lite#aboutus

Comment: As you need the min value to 100 then how you need the current value to 1 or 2, can you update some clearly,,, Are you expect something like this http://roundsliderui.com/demos.html ?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, i was able to accomplish this by setting the data-max value to 1 or 2 and the value of the input field to 1 or 2 respectively.